# How to allow database operations to take place in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am new to database in Android but now I know the way to apply CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations on an activity but in case of fragments, getWritableDatabase() is not working. I would like to know the best way to apply CRUD operations in fragments. 
In activities, I made a class to handle database operations and then made its' object in the activity and was able to work on it thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DbHelper helper = DbHelper.getInstance(getContext());
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();`
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Here I tried to illustrate calling `db` from `fragment` class :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = context.getWritableDatabase(); // 'this' for activity
```

Initialize `db` object inside `onAttach()` or `onActivityCreated()` any other method :
[`onAttach()` is preferable]

```
public Cursor getAllData() {
  Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME, null);
  return result; 
}
```

**Tips:** You should use these type of `db` calls into the `background threads`, not to invoke or block the `UI thread` which will result a better performance.